Are these levels of RF radiation harmful?
I live on the top floor of a building that has four 5G antennas on the roof. The house is curved, and from my viewpoint, I can partially see one of the antennas pointing towards me. Curious about the possible RF radiation levels, I decided to order this meter: Amazon Link.
I took readings all over my apartment, around the house, and in the neighborhood. The average reading outside was ~400 mV/m. Near my building, it was ~700 mV/m. In my apartment, it averaged about 100-600 mV/m, depending on the direction and room. However, in one of my rooms, from which I can see the antenna, if I move close to the window, the readings go up to 3 V/m. If I open the window and extend my hand outside, I can get around 8 V/m.
For comparison, I placed this meter next to my Wifi 6 router and could get a maximum reading of 3 V/m. Does this mean that sleeping in that one room is the same as having a powerful Wifi 6 router under my pillow? Are these levels safe, or should I be concerned?

https://www.fcc.gov/engineering-technology/electromagnetic-compatibility-division/radio-frequency-safety/faq/rf-safety has some useful information. Readings in V/m are not particularly useful.

If you are interested in Xray radiation, see XKCD's Radiation Dose Chart

The frequency of 5G ranges from 1GHz to 40GHz (Source: Nokia, they manufacture some of the networking devices that provide 5G: https://www.nokia.com/thought-leadership/articles/spectrum-bands-5g-world/).
These frequencies are in what is known as the millimeter range, due to the length of the waves that they produce.
The product you share is interesting because specifically in Amazon is close to other devices that specifically state they are meant to measure 5G antennas.

The new bands for 5G are in the higher band ranges, which are well outside the measuring capacity of most EMF measuring devices. All other frequencies already existed prior to the introduction of 5G.
The units that you shared are for measuring electric fields (units, volts per meter or V/m), and the devices can also measure magnetic fields (I think I have seen measurements in gauss units). In general, I think what is important to know besides the electric field strength, is the frequency (or ranges of frequencies) which are being measured.
Due to the frequency of 5G, the radiation for these antennas are considered in technical terms as non-ionizing radiation. This means that the frequency is low (compared to ionizing radiation which covers ultra violet, x-rays, etc.), and non-ionizing radiation means that there is not enough energy to remove electrons from atoms or molecules.
This means that the energy that the electromagnetic waves carry cannot, for the most part (as there are different types of molecules all over), cause damage to atoms or molecules.
There are several resources that support this information, and while those devices do measure something, what they specifically measure is more important, as this gives a complete picture of what exactly is being measured.
As for available literature, a systematic review of biological effects of exposure to static electric fields in humans and vertebrates is openly available here:
https://ehjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12940-017-0248-y
Another study for local heating of human skin by millimeter waves is available here:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15931684/
The abstract states that they used peak intensities of 55 and 208 mW/cm$^2$.
To give some perspective, a measured field of 8 V/m yields approximately 0.0265 mW/cm$^2$. This conversion also requires the field to be incident in vacuum (ca. 377 $\Omega$), but you might have seen that having the window closed already reduces the field to 3V/m, so there is very strong absorption by glass and walls of this radiation already.
In my estimation, you would need to have fields as strong as 455V/m incident in vacuum (that means, directly pointed at skin) to raise the temperature by a few degrees centigrade (and there is strong dependence on where the wave is impinging to raise the temperature at different rates).
In summary: The effect that you would see would be a minuscule temperature raise on the skin level for the amount of radiation measured by the device. The power rates also would differ but in my opinion, the radiation should not present any significant damage to a person from most commercially available antennas.


Thank you, this was very detailed. The device also measures mW/cm², and I was able to get around 1.5 mW/cm² inside and 250 mW/cm² outside. I'm quite sure that 5G towers operate at 5 GHz frequency in my country. RF limits set by the WHO are 1 W/m² and 0.1 W/m² in residential areas. Outside my window, it's above the recommended level. I understand that this radiation is not ionizing, but it could have some health effects. Would these levels worry you if you were in my place?

I found another paper regarding 5G radiation in specific conditions from chinese researchers: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41605-024-00452-1 as I imagined, the power density variates with, for example, if you are using the network or not, which makes sense as if you need more data, then you will get more power density in the direction of the device.  Nonetheless for example in fig. 6 there is very high power (still <1W/cm²) very close to the antenna and then it sharply drops as distance increases.

As I mentioned, the worst thing that RF signals at the frequency of 5G is a small increase of the temperature at the skin level, but only if you have the beam directly focused and pointed towards specific points. Something important to note is that antennas are strongly deviating other than at the focus, therefore you would also see a sharp decrease of power if you move the measuring device up, down and sideways. In my opinion the danger is not significant based on the evidence available now, and understanding the underlying physics of the signal strongly helps to feel more confident about it.

For comparison, the voltage across the terminals of a typical coin battery is about $3$ V. I just measured the length of such a battery. It was $3$ mm. That works out to a field of $1000$ V/m.
You might be concerned if you were at the the focus of a large antenna, in the same way that you would be concerned about the focus of a large magnifying glass. For a large dish, a few meters across, it is like a microwave oven. You can cook a potato at the focus. Without a focus, it is more like being bathed in moonlight.
